# Flask RESTful api put error

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a Post model as follows -

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self, body, user_id):
        self.likes = 0
        self.body = body
        self.user_id = user_id
```

I am unable to update objects using the PUT request. Here is my code -

```
class UserPost(Resource):
    def get(self, post_id):
        print(post_id)
        return marshal(Post.query.get(post_id), post_fields)

    def put(self, post_id):
        post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
        args = post_parser.parse_args()
        print args
        for k, v in args.iteritems():
            if v is not None:
                post.__dict__[k] = v

                db.session.add(post)
                db.session.commit()
        return marshal(post, post_fields)
```

The Post object is not updated.

Comment: Did you try: `@app.route('/path', methods=['PUT', 'POST'])`

Comment: no error, the object doesnt update and the old one is returned.

Comment: @Valijon the put request is working. the update doesn't work.

Comment: maybe `v` is an empty string? In that case `is not None` check will fail.

Comment: nope, I've checked with the debugger, v isn't blank. Infact the object is updated temporarily, but isn't somehow saved.

Comment: ok, so please, include that info next time, it would save some time

Comment: maybe try using `setattr` instead of manually updating `post.__dict__`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99019/discussion-between-utkbansal-and-mic4ael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually updating the `post.__dict__` use `setattr`.